# copying between instances of different variant template classes

Tags: c++, boost, variant

Why does one variant assignment compile while the other does not? The template instances do not share any types and `char` could be converted to `int`, say. What is `boost::variant` trying to do, that it cannot do in the case of the first assignment and that it can do in the case of the second assignment? Error is below.

```
#include <string>

#include "boost/variant.hpp"

int main()
{
  boost::variant<char> v1;
  boost::variant<std::string, int, double> v2;

  v1 = v2; // compile error
  v2 = v1; // compiles fine

  return 0;
}
```

---

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/variant.hpp:17:0,
                 from v.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp: In instantiation of 'int boost::variant<T0, TN>::convert_copy_into::internal_visit(T&, int) const [with T = const std::basic_string<char>; T0_ = char; TN = {}]':
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:113:9:   required from 'typename Visitor::result_type boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke_impl(int, Visitor&, VoidPtrCV, T*, mpl_::true_) [with Visitor = boost::variant<char>::convert_copy_into; VoidPtrCV = const void*; T = std::basic_string<char>; typename Visitor::result_type = int; mpl_::true_ = mpl_::bool_<true>]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:156:9:   required from 'typename Visitor::result_type boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_invoke(int, Visitor&, VoidPtrCV, T*, NoBackupFlag, int) [with Visitor = boost::variant<char>::convert_copy_into; VoidPtrCV = const void*; T = std::basic_string<char>; NoBackupFlag = boost::variant<std::basic_string<char>, int, double>::has_fallback_type_; typename Visitor::result_type = int]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/visitation_impl.hpp:237:5:   required from 'typename Visitor::result_type boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl(int, int, Visitor&, VoidPtrCV, mpl_::false_, NoBackupFlag, Which*, step0*) [with Which = mpl_::int_<0>; step0 = boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_step<boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<3l>, std::basic_string<char>, boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<2l>, int, boost::mpl::l_item<mpl_::long_<1l>, double, boost::mpl::l_end> > > >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_end> >; Visitor = boost::variant<char>::convert_copy_into; VoidPtrCV = const void*; NoBackupFlag = boost::variant<std::basic_string<char>, int, double>::has_fallback_type_; typename Visitor::result_type = int; mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2245:13:   required from 'static typename Visitor::result_type boost::variant<T0, TN>::internal_apply_visitor_impl(int, int, Visitor&, VoidPtrCV) [with Visitor = boost::variant<char>::convert_copy_into; VoidPtrCV = const void*; T0_ = std::basic_string<char>; TN = {int, double}; typename Visitor::result_type = int]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2267:13:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1581:13:   required from 'void boost::variant<T0, TN>::convert_construct_variant(Variant&) [with Variant = const boost::variant<std::basic_string<char>, int, double>; T0_ = char; TN = {}]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1628:42:   required from 'void boost::variant<T0, TN>::convert_construct(const boost::variant<U0, UN ...>&, long int) [with U0 = std::basic_string<char>; UN = {int, double}; T0_ = char; TN = {}]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1649:38:   required from 'boost::variant<T0, TN>::variant(const T&) [with T = boost::variant<std::basic_string<char>, int, double>; T0_ = char; TN = {}]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2059:29:   required from 'void boost::variant<T0, TN>::assign(const T&) [with T = boost::variant<std::basic_string<char>, int, double>; T0_ = char; TN = {}]'
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2099:19:   required from 'boost::variant<T0, TN>& boost::variant<T0, TN>::operator=(const T&) [with T = boost::variant<std::basic_string<char>, int, double>; T0_ = char; TN = {}]'
v.cpp:10:6:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1366:61: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::variant<char>::initializer::initialize(void* const&, const std::basic_string<char>&)'
             return initializer::initialize(storage_, operand);
                                                             ^
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1366:61: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:32:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant.hpp:17,
                 from v.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:104:24: note: static int boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair, Iterator>::initializer_node::initialize(void*, boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair, Iterator>::initializer_node::param_T) [with BaseIndexPair = boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root, mpl_::int_<0> >; Iterator = boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list1<char> >; boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair, Iterator>::initializer_node::param_T = const char&]
             static int initialize(void* dest, param_T operand)
                        ^
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:104:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const std::basic_string<char>' to 'boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root, mpl_::int_<0> >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list1<char> > >::initializer_node::param_T {aka const char&}'
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:115:24: note: static int boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair, Iterator>::initializer_node::initialize(void*, boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair, Iterator>::initializer_node::param2_T) [with BaseIndexPair = boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root, mpl_::int_<0> >; Iterator = boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list1<char> >; boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<BaseIndexPair, Iterator>::initializer_node::param2_T = char&&]
             static int initialize(void* dest, param2_T operand)
                        ^
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:115:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const std::basic_string<char>' to 'boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node::apply<boost::mpl::pair<boost::detail::variant::initializer_root, mpl_::int_<0> >, boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::list1<char> > >::initializer_node::param2_T {aka char&&}'
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:149:17: note: static void boost::detail::variant::initializer_root::initialize()
     static void initialize();
                 ^
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:149:17: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` definitely can be stored in an `int` but the converse is not always true.  Therefore the one that fails to compile would be unsafe at runtime, so you're probably better off with it failing.  Cast the `int` to a `char` if you must.

Comment: So, it is not trying to convert (i.e. cast) itself, but copy literally. Still, you need to take into account, that char != int. So, a conversion is made.

Comment: Implicit conversions are implicit

Comment: The converse is also true: `int i = 10; char c = i;` is pretty valid. Also, `variant<char> v1; variant<int> v2; v1 = v2;` is valid as well.

Comment: @IgorR. You mean it should but isn't?

Comment: @user1095108 I mean the problem isn't the conversion from `int` to `char`.

Comment: You answer is technically incorrect as sizeof(char) <= sizeof(int). An int could be stored in there.

Comment: @user1095108: I don't understand what you mean.  I am claiming that an int may not fit in a char.  Are you claiming it can?

Comment: You need to write that in your answer, currently it says "but the converse is not true", you need to insert a "may" into your answer.

Comment: @user1095108: OK, I added an "always" in there to clarify.

Comment: I still find it strange, as, a `char` can also be implicitly converted into a `double`.